# What type of font are used for the subtitles in this video?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification, typefaces, font-design

What type of font is used for the subtitles in this Youtube video linked below?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xPYHygck6o&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Downvoted because I don't think it's a graphic design question.

Answer (score 0):

It's Helvetica with an outline.